# create parameters in joomla

Tags: joomla

I created parameters in templateDetails.xml as

```
<params>
<param name="font-size" value="12" />
</params>
```

Where will this parameter be visible?

Answer (score 2):

It's visible in the admin back-end when you click on the template in the template list